# How to add reward points for new registration and social media likes in opencart?

Tags: opencart

How to add reward points for new registration and social media likes in opencart, I am using opencart version 1.5x. I want to assign reward points to customers on registration and also assign them reward points for social media likes and share. Please can anyone help me out with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a good read through this: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=56030 there's quite detailed instruction on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Set a default user group , when a new customer registered they will on that group.
Now you can edit that group setting in the admin panel.